# Why no TIME-WAIT connect when using haproxy with redis

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, redis, haproxy

I'm using Haproxy to check Redis server living status. One problem we may always face is, no enough port available after a while, cuz Haproxy might leave a ton of TIME-WAIT sockets there. But, in fact, I cannot find any TIME-WAIT socket when using haproxy+redis. Cannot understand why.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

see fd.c:

```
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER,
           (struct linger *) &nolinger, sizeof(struct linger));
```